# Overlaying ggmap and ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I am trying to display ggplot on top of ggmap.

```
library(patchwork)
ggmap(seoul) + ggplot(data = install_time_df) +
  geom_point(aes(x = long, y = lat, size = capa_sum),
             color = "black", alpha = 0.55)
```

I have tried patchwork library, but it displays them side by side not overlaying on the same display.
[image]

Without patchwork, I get the following error message:

> Error : Can't add `gg_heat` to a ggplot object.
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: Can you make your question [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like following

```
ggmap(seoul) + 
  geom_point(data = install_time_df, aes(x = long, y = lat, size = capa_sum),
             color = "black", alpha = 0.55)
```